# Personal data inside question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I stumbled upon this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136413/i-want-to-make-a-program-to-receive-sms-and-run-responding-command-for-sms-in-vi

It contains the OP number, and is also off topic I think because he is not asking a specific question.

What to do in cases like this? Do i edit out the personal data or just flag it as too broad?

Comment: There is no privacy issue if an OP chooses to publish their private information - it was maybe a bit spammy in this case. Personal data belonging to other people (e.g. in screenshots) is a big no-no, and mods/devs will collaborate here to have such material burninated. Flag if you see that sort of thing, as it needs to be manually removed from edit history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vote to close the question and edit out the personal information. In this case the personal info was in the form of a signature, so just edit it out. The OP put it there on purpose, not knowing about the site policy against adding signatures to posts.